# Google search console two problems mobile technologies Clickable elements too close together and The content is wider than the screen

Tags: joomla3.0

Google search console has reported 2 issues on my mobile devices https://www.elektrosolary.pl
1. Clickable elements too close to each other
2. The content is wider than the screen
I checked on my mobile devices and this problem does not occur. What exactly do I need to improve to prevent these error messages from Google search console?

Comment: This is mostly going to be CSS tweaks.  Please share the URL

Comment: https://www.elektrosolary.pl

Answer (score 0):

Taking a quick look, I think the issues are:

**1. Clickable elements too close to each other.**
Look at your list items and put a margin-bottom between each item

**2. Content Wider than the screen**
Click the Facebook tab and that is not resizing to entirely fit off the phone.  Use CSS to downsize on mobile or just disable on mobile only.